# Get the screen location of a wxTaskBarIcon

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, taskbar

I have a `wxTaskBarIcon` in my application which gets added to the taskbar when the app is running. I want to know the `location of this icon` but haven't been able to do this so far.
I need the location because I want to open a custom frame (not menu) at that location.
Is it even possible to get the location since wxTaskBarIcon derives directly from wxObject and so has no such functions to get the location?
Is there any other way in which I should approach to get it working?
Any ideas or code will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there seems to be no way to get the position you require. For example an example using a custom balloon on the [wxWiki](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxTaskBarIcon) performs the popup in the corner as it does not know the correct location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link, Steve. Much appreciated!